# Mount remote docker instance to my OSX file system

Tags: ssh, docker, kubernetes

I need to be able to develop on osx off a docker instance running on a remote server.

The docker instance would be running on Google compute engine using kubernetes.

On my OSX I need to be able to mount the docker file system so that I can code in Atom ( for example ) and also have terminal so I can run run git tool etc.

The reason being, so that I can easily and quickly do cross device testing of mobile web apps.

I am wondering if I can do this ?

I noticed the remote api is stable now, so this seems doable. but am looking for tip / URLs from others to help me set this up for myself and the team. It will make development alot smoother.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you wana do this? Changing a running container and then you wanna commit the changes of the container to use it later? We use containers everywhere but we follow this process: Develop local, build container, publish container to private registrie, staging and prod server can update there containers over the priv registry.

Comment: I have had success with a running docker from a prebuilt Vagrant box when I need to mount volumes outside of the Docker root in OSX

Comment: @rene I need it because it allows testing on devices that are remote from us quickly. These devices are in data centres and so they need to point to a URL they can reach. Develops can then live code and see the changes in all devices at once. It speeds up coding because you see a bug occurring in one device versus another.

Comment: @ Parris ah that reminds me. I can use Terraform to automate this deployment. They have CGE support last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter into the context of the container using kubectl exec:

http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/getting-into-containers.html

However, we don't yet have a mechanism to make it easy to retrieve a saved Docker image.

You'd need to ssh into the node in order to do that.

If you'd like better support for your use case, please file a feature request with as many details about your scenario as you can:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/new

Comment: Added as a feature request. #17341